# PHP session index undefined after header redirection?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-state, var-dump

I have struggled with this for hours but I can't get it to work. When I do a redirection to another PHP page, all my session variables are null. I am on xampp server.

session.php

```
<?php
     session_start();
     if(isset($_POST['submitted']))                                                                                         
     {   
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = "MAX";
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        header("Location: http://localhost:8080/secure login/session2.php");     
        die();
     }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
<head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-    1" /> 
    <title>You Logged In</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form action="session.php" method="post">
        <div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

session2.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
<head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
    <title>You Logged In</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="main"> 
        <?php 
            echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';
            echo 'You are welcome to session2.php <br></br>'; 
            if (isset($_SESSION['first_name'])) 
            { 
                echo $_SESSION['first_name'] . "<br></br>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Your session doesn't exist. I hate php <br></br>";
                echo $_SESSION['first_name'];
            }
        ?>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The session doesn't save, and the output is;

```
Array
(
)
You are welcome to session2.php
Your session doesn't exist. I hate php
Notice: Undefined index: first_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\secure login\session2.php on line 28
```

I have tried other things like changing where session variables are saved from xampp/tmp to another directory, but this didn't solve the problem. I have a program that I need to keep a user logged in when I do a redirection but this has blocked me for more than a day.

UPDATE:

The space between the directories wasn't the problem, it temporarily solved the problem but that was because there wasn't cache for the new directory yet. Any way, for a few more days, I debugged and realized that I was running two programs on my localhost. Both were using sessions, and so if one terminates the session, it also terminates the session for the other since localhost is like a domain name and there exists only one session. Particularly, the logout.php of my other program was not destroying the session but was rather jumbling it up were by you have to remove browser cache do unjumble it. I was emptying session array, destroying the session, and destroying the cookie, this was the problem and so I couldn't login again. All I had to do was just destroy the session only;

See -> [Killing off Global Session Variable as a logout button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000066/killing-off-global-session-variable-as-a-logout-button)

Comment: This code works for me as is (well, I am not on a local host so I had to change that, but other than that all works)

Comment: Take a look [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm)

Comment: @Matt dathew , what is your URL "http://localhost:8080/secure login/session2.php"  meaning ? is "secure login" is just an example word ?what is your absolute URL of "session.php" ?

Comment: secure login is a diectory in my xampp htdocs folder, where I am coding from

Comment: Has this worked for anyone at localhost?

Comment: yes , for me it is working :)

Comment: what is your URL for session.php ? Also check this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect

Comment: This is my url for session.php..... http://localhost:8080/secure%20login/session.php     I don't understand why it doesn't work for me. Did you change anything in the code I have given?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83162/discussion-between-kanishka-panamaldeniya-and-matt-dathew).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are having problem because you have a space in name `secure login`

```
localhost:8080/secure%20login/session.php
```

So please try to change the name with underscore  `secure_login` and also change your code

```
<?php
     session_start();
     if(isset($_POST['submitted']))                                                                                         
     {   
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = "MAX";
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        header("Location: http://localhost:8080/secure_login/session2.php");     
        die();
     }
?>
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT. This worked, at first I hadn't noticed that you included the " _ ". I included it and it worked.

Comment: It is also important to notice that php sessions don't always work. It worked for me, but stopped working 3 hours later when I checked it again.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely due to the `die()` call, I think that causes it not to write the session.

Try `session_write_close();` prior to it.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
        $user = $_SESSION['first_name'] = "MAX";

        if(isset($user))
        {
            header("Location: http://localhost:8080/secure login/session2.php");
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: ");//index page
        }
    }
?>
```

In `$user = $_SESSION['first_name'] = "MAX";`

first `$_SESSION['first_name'] = "MAX";` will execute, then result will be assign to `$user`. so in `isset($user)` it Check whether set

Comment: Might want to adjust this `$user = $_SESSION['first_name'] = "MAX";`

Comment: Your solution redirects me to the next page, but then output remains the same. $user and $_SESSION are not set on session2.php. Inform me if this worked for you

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, check if there any white spaces before starting the `<?php` tag in `session.php` and `session2.php` file.

Than remove `var_dump($_SESSION);` from `session.php`.

and change the folder name to secure_login

Comment: Yes, I've checked this and it's works. Please change your folder name to secure_login. This might be the reason.